# TypeError: must be str, not bytes - python sparql-client 3.6

Tags: python, sparql, endpoint, dbpedia

I tried to query the super classes for a given class using python sparql-client 3.6. Using the following code snippet

```
dbo_prefix = 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/'
_class = 'PoliticalParty'
s = sparql.Service('http://dbpedia.org/sparql', "utf-8", "GET")
statement = 'SELECT distinct ?superclass WHERE { dbo:%s rdfs:subClassOf* ?superclass. ' \
            'FILTER (strstarts(str(?superclass), "%s"))}' % (_class, dbo_prefix)
print(statement)
result = s.query(statement)
for row in result.fetchone():
    print(row)
```

But it crashes as in the StackTrace below. I debugged the code and I found inside the lib (sparql.py) it converted the type from str to bytes then it crashes before sending the query.
[image]

I tried the generated query directly at the [endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) and it retrieved the results correctly.

Comment: use SPARQLWrapper if this API doesn't work, or contact the devs